# Oracle SQL Developer - SQL Command Not Properly Entered

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having a bit of an issue with Oracle SQL Developer.  I'm trying to write an SQL query (all actual data have been replaced with metasyntactic variable names):

```
UPDATE FOO
  SET BAR='BAR',BAZ='BAZ'
  WHERE UPPER(QUX)=UPPER('qux'), UPPER(QUUX)=UPPER('quux'), UPPER(CORGE)=UPPER('corge'), UPPER(GRAULT)=UPPER('grault');
```

Oracle is giving me the error "SQL command not properly ended" and I don't know why.  I'm pretty sure I did something wrong; can someone please let me know what that is?  Thanks!

Comment: `WHERE` clause items should be separated by `AND`, not commas.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I knew I had made some kind of stupid mistake, but I didn't know exactly what it was.

As you can probably tell, I'm a complete newbie when it comes to SQL.

Comment: I'm going to close the question as it's just a simple syntax mistake. Glad that I could help/.